# how to use gmock and gtest in android projects using cmake

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk, googletest

I have been trying to find a good tutorial or a reference to a project that uses gmock and gtest for android. so far all the information I have seen either don't work, outdated, or hard to follow. do any of you have experience setting up an Android project to use gtest/gmock ? is it possible to run the test on my local computer or the only option is to cross compile and generate an APK ? how can i get started ?

Comment: Please, show (describe in the question post) **what exactly have you tried**. "is it possible to run the test on my local computer" - You can run tests only on the machine which corresponds to the **target platform**. If your target platform is Android, then you can run tests on Android only (or on the some emulator).

Comment: _"or the only option is to cross compile and generate an APK"_ These are unit tests for native code, so you wouldn't build an APK but a native executable, which you then execute in an Android emulator (or possibly on a rooted device).